# Socket.io not config properly for heroku production

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku, socket.io

I'm a newbie with websocket but the socket.io works properly locally:

```
const corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
  methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
  allowedHeaders: ['Authorization'],
  credentials: true
};
const io = new SocketIO(httpServer, {
  cors: corsOptions
});
```

But when I try on production with heroku I get the error: GET https://futureblend.herokuapp.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OYyUGQY 404 (Not Found).

On my frontend side of the code which I use reactjs, this is how I listen to the socket:

```
const socket = io('wss://example.herokuapp.com', {
        withCredentials: true,
        extraHeaders: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      });

    socket.on('connect', () => {
      console.log('Socket connected');
      // Perform actions when the socket is connected
    });

    socket.on('jobStatusUpdated', (data) => {
      console.log('Received server update:', data);
      // Process the server update
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
      console.log('Socket disconnected');
      // Perform actions when the socket is disconnected
    });
```

I have tried with https, wws but none are working.

This is the setup in my backend for https request with socket:

```
const app = express();
const httpsServer = createServer({
  key: fs.readFileSync("./server.key"),
  cert: fs.readFileSync("./server.cert")
}, app);
const corsOptions = {
  origin: '*',
  methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
  allowedHeaders: ['Authorization'],
  credentials: true
};
const io = new SocketIO(httpsServer, {
  cors: corsOptions
});
```

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('A client connected');

  // Handle events from the client
  socket.on('someEvent', (data) => {
    console.log('Received data:', data);
    // Perform actions based on the received data
  });

  // Send updates to the client
  setInterval(() => {
    const message = 'This is a server update';
    socket.emit('serverUpdate', message);
  }, 5000);

  socket.on('jobStatusUpdated', (data) => {
    console.log('Received job status update from client:', data);
    // Perform actions based on the received job status update
  });

  // Handle disconnection
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('A client disconnected');
  });
});

httpsServer.listen(process.env.SERVER || 3002, () => {
  console.log('Socket.IO server is listening on port 3002');
});
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.